# Can BES 5.0 Express database be migrated from SQL Server 2005 Express to SQL Server 2008 R2 Express?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, bes

Would there be any issues for cross migration of database from SQL Server 2005 Express to SQL Server 2008 R2 for blackberry configuration database and database in general?

If the database is backup on SQL Server 2005, and then restored to SQL Server 2008, would there be any changes in the database structure/schema etc. that will cause application to break? Would the migrated database 'upgrade' itself when restored to new SQL Server 2008?

From my understanding, a possible worst case scenario is that all blackberry phone will have to be re-activated.

### The following is a reply from expert-exchange.

BlackBerry Express 5.0.3 supports Microsoft SQL 2008 Express SP1 and is indeed the recommended version.

Microsoft SQL 2008 Express R2 is supported.

Please see the article below:

http://us.blackberry.com/support/software/server_express_exchange_aug_10_11.pdf

Please see the article below for details on how to migrate:

http://btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB03112

Answer (score 0):

When you restore the database to the 2008 instance the database will be upgraded and you would just need to point the application to the new server\instance.  If you have to move back to the 2005 version you would lose any changes to the 2008 database because you cannot backup and restore a SQL database to a lower version instance.  Everything pretty much depends on your application vendor; if they support the version then there should be no problem.